# Keyboard Driver for IOS : Background app intercepts bluetooth keyboard input

Tags: ios, keyboard, driver

I have rigged a custom bluetooth keyboard that needs drivers on the OS to interpret and output the desired characters.  This can be easily done on Windows.  However, I would like to have my keyboard work with IOS.

Do I need to get a background app to intercept the input and broadcast to foreground app?
Should I learn about Bluetooth driver?
What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Peter

Comment: DM Have you found a solution to this issue? I need to run a service in background and I think this question's solution can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't implement iOS keyboard drivers without Apple's co-operation, so you're probably out of luck. There is no standard way on iOS to broadcast keystrokes to the foreground app either. You should probably try and get your custom bluetooth keyboard to implement the standard Bluetooth keyboard interface.